# Making a custom magical armor piece clothing

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, armor

One of my players is playing 5e.

A homebrew class called Princess and she can't wear armor, and she wants a magical dress. But I am not sure how to make a unique magical item armor for a dress.

I am trying to find something that fits the class that it would be beneficial to the class itself since its not a fighter. Does anyone have any suggestion on what I can make it? She wants a magical princess gown. I can't find any rules on it other than using spell slots but Princess's don't have spell slots so its I was giving my players one special piece of equipment. I would really love the help.

*Edited question*

I want the dress to enhance the class Since at 2nd level does get the Chrismatic Armor. So the dress Idea I wanted to have some special abilities that actually enhance the abilities of the class.I was getting some ideas. Like making regenerate so its not easily destroyed. I was just pretty seeing seeing other people could come up with ideas to help me brainstorm. I never seen a class like this before. The class runs of Majestic Talents which the class gives you ability to use talents from other classes as well.

So I am looking for the ideas of something like how a mage can get Robes of the Archmagi, How it gives bonuses for mages, I was looking for something like that but a dress to enhance the class statistically to give the princess class a little more it can do. So more a less an enhancer.

So far I didn't get to finish all the suggestions, I was just looking for help to brain storm things the dress can do but I kind want it to enhance the class.
Exmaples
1: Dress repairs itself
2: Makes the ability: Inspiring Touch better like giving it a range

Since the class by no means a fighter. I am trying to come up with a weapon and the dress to utlize the class a bit more and flush it.

**Is that a bit better of what I am looking help with?**

[image: Princess Class 1]
[image: Princess Class 2]

More details on the archetypes on the [imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXUcG.jpg).

Comment: @Tristian Please [don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534).

Comment: Welcome to Role-playing Games! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a good introduction to how the site works. Unfortunately brainstorming questions don't work in the Stack Exchange site format. As a rule they result in a list of ideas with [no obvious way for voters to tell which answers are better than others](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). If you have a specific problem that can have a right answers we could help with that. Otherwise, you may just actually want a [chat room or discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack.

Answer (score 2):

While this is Homebrew and very subjective as a question a magical set of armor seems to be redundant for the Homebrew class. **Take a look at the ability labeled "charismatic Armor"** as it gives the Player a higher armor class than usual.

You could also offer a sort of +1 set of clothing, adding a +1 to AC, but that would make the bonus to AC that the Charismatic Armor ability gets redundant as it doesn't work with armor.

Outside of that maybe taking a look at some sort of charm magic item would inspire what this sort of class would need and want as clothing, but that is your call.

Comment: well I am not exactly looking to make it an AC thing but more of giving the dress aibiliies hat will help he class out more so than AC. A way to enhance the class itself. I miss the old dnd charts with the list of abilities items can get. So I am more looking for enchancement abilities that work with the class iself, if that makes sense? I looked at other magical armor its more suited for armor not so much clothing. I am just looking for suggestion. Since their not a fighter their more support. So really a dress that enhances that support. PS: is the charm magical items in the DM Book?

Comment: @HimekoTakahashi There are many magic items in the DMG that all have abilities and rarities. Unless you are fine with giving your character's a rather strong item though a level 1 magical dress might be lackluster. I suggest looking at the bardic instruments, the magical ones, for inspiration. IT's on pg. 176 of the DMG and generally each instrument can give spells. All are atleast uncommon, some can charm and cure wounds and the like. If you meant items for the class it self, that's something you'd have to really think about. Maybe something that gives more inspiring callcharges.

Comment: You're right that a strictly AC-boosting item would count as armor and override Charismatic Armor. But a charisma-boosting item (see the strength-boosting Belt of Giant Strength) would stack with this feature and provide an AC boost (among other things).

Comment: Updated first post of something more of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an easy problem. Magic just adjusts reality. The princess seems a little too defensive. You can pick a random good thing and give the character advantage to it. Like negotiating, intimidate or charisma checks. Repel magic with one charge that resets after two long rests. It could be a nice quality of life spell like purge bad smells, summon serene garden, tame wild mount, or detect fresh water.
The sky is the limit.

I have a player being a magic archer from one of the new books and he has gotten a lot of milage out a cantrip that cleans soiled things.

Comment: thats an intersting concept ya the abilites to work well with the class itself is what I am really looking fo you guys are giving some nice ideas. though I am open to more ideas. I agree the sky is he limit with this is why I thought it was a neat idea.